# Update query in dynamoDb throws exception

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm fairly new to DynamoDb. I have to update an attribute called status and modifiedTime in a table, using partition key which is id and sort key which is number. My code below throws

The provided key element does not match the schema exception. Could someone please help here to find what am I missing here ?

```
public static UpdateItemSpec updateData(String id, int number, String status, long modifiedTime) {
    String partitionKey = "id";
    String statusAttribute = "status";
    String modifiedTimeAttribute = "modifiedTime";
    String numberAttribute = "number";

    String expressionAttributeForStatus = "#s";
    String expressionAttributeForModifiedTime = "#m";
    String expressionAttributeForNumber = "#b";

    return new UpdateItemSpec()
            .withPrimaryKey(new PrimaryKey(partitionKey, id))
            .withConditionExpression("#b = :Num")
            .withUpdateExpression("SET " + expressionAttributeForStatus + " = :newStatus, " +
                    expressionAttributeForModifiedTime + " = :newModifiedTime")
            .withNameMap(new NameMap()
                    .with(expressionAttributeForStatus, statusAttribute)
                    .with(expressionAttributeForModifiedTime, modifiedTimeAttribute)
                    .with(expressionAttributeForNumber, numberAttribute))
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                    .with(":newStatus", status)
                    .with(":newModifiedTime", modifiedTime)
                    .with(":Num", number))
            .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.UPDATED_NEW);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primary key takes the following parameters:

`PrimaryKey(String hashKeyName, Object hashKeyValue, String rangeKeyName, Object rangeKeyValue)`

In your case, you don't pass in the full primary key, which should contain both your partition and sort key.